# ¿Cómo traer los registros con un año de antigüedad en SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla con nombre `TB_Order` la cual tiene un campo el cual se llama `dateadd` que guarda la fecha de creación del registro  necesito traer los datos que tienen un año de antigüedad  teniendo en cuenta el la columna nombrada anteriormente estoy intentando algo así SELECT * FROM `TB_Order WHERE [dateAdd] <=  DATEADD(DAY,-10,[dateAdd])` pero aun no encuentro la solución de antemano gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si lo que necesitas es son los datos de un año de antiguedad no deberia ser con day

```
select * from TB_Order WHERE [dateAdd] <= DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())
```

donde a la fecha actual le restas un año